# 01403. 00000 - "no data found"

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm updating my docmeta table but i get the

ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 25
01403. 00000 -  "no data found" error

Below is the query. How can i get rid of this error?

```
DECLARE 
varPayTerm varchar2(300);
BEGIN
FOR X  IN(
SELECT 
  d.did, d.xproject_id
FROM 
  revisions r,
  (SELECT DDOCNAME, MAX(DID) mDID
   FROM 
    REVISIONS REV
   WHERE
    dcreatedate >='01-Jan-14'
   GROUP BY 
    DDOCNAME
  ) RevLatestID,
   docmeta d
  --temp_project p 
WHERE  
  RevLatestID.mdid = r.did
  and d.did = r.did
)  
 loop

select paymentterm 
into varPayTerm 
from project where pid = X.xproject_id and paymentterm is not null;

update docmeta 
  set xpaymentterm= varPayTerm
where did=X.dID
     and xproject_id =  X.xproject_id;
END LOOP;
END ;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `SELECT...INTO` statements is returning no rows
If it is valid for no rows to be returned, and you want to continue you can catch and ignore the NO_DATA_FOUND exception like this:

```
   ...
    BEGIN
      SELECT ... INTO...;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        paymentterm := 0; 
   -- or ant msg you want
    then return 'no data here';
    END;
    ...
```

Comment: Up_One for me :) KKKK